# git - local repository - how to manage different customer config files with same names

Tags: git

I want to use git to manage a set of code files and a set of customer specific configuration files.

On the server are several directories, two per customer: one test, one production.

I want to be able to use git to track changes, etc. to the code files, and to the customer specific configuration files, but I don't want to be merging the config files back to the master branch.

In other words, I want to be able to maintain history of the configuration files (in each test and production directory), and be able to checkout specific versions of the code in to either a customer's test or production directory.

I thought I could just create a branch for each customer and maintain their config files on those branches, but whenever I check out the master branch, the config files, since they aren't part of the config branch, they get deleted.

Do I need to use two different repositories to handle this?

How do I switch which repository to use when I want to make changes to either the code or config files?

I don't want to create custom config files and rename them to the real config filenames, because everytime I checkout the master, I will get every customer's config file in a particular customer's directory.

There must be an easy way to do this?

Comment: Changes across branches are not unified unless the branches merge at some point.  Since you don't want to do that, it sounds like Git may not be the right approach for this; some form of secrets management or configuration management would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the following assumptions I would propose to you this solution:

### Assumptions

- You want to track the code with `git`
- You want to track the config files (per customer) with `git`

### Possible solution

I think you could get away with the following setup:

- Having a `master` branch that contains only the code and no configuration
- Having two branches per customer e.g. `customerA-prod` and `customerA-test`

If possible commit bugfixes that apply to all customers to the `master` branch and merge it back into the customer branches.

For customer specific alterations use only the customer branches.

In general try to avoid merging customer branches into `master`.

If it is really necessary make sure that you do not merge any configuration files onto `master` (delete them, so that `master` stays clear of config files).

With this proposed setup I think it should be possible to share the code (where needed), track the history of the config files (per customer/environment).

### Unclear specification

> but whenever I check out the master branch, the config files, since they aren't part of the config branch, they get deleted

I don't understand the problem here.

Maybe you need some customers config files on `master` in order to develop?
If so you could check out the config files (while still avoiding to commit them by doing something like this)

```
$ git checkout customerA-prod -- <path-to-config-file>
$ git reset HEAD -- <path-to-config-file>
$ # work, commit (but avoid adding the config file)
```

The `git checkout <branch> -- <file>` syntax is useful to get files as they are on other branches onto your current branch.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes, thank you - I hit upon that general solution as well.

What I meant by the config files disappearing, was that when I want to pull a new copy of the master in one of the customer directories, the master's copy of the config file is pulled. To work around that, I just have to do an additional git co customer_branch config file.

There is an additional challenge, when I want to make a change to a customer's config file, git complains that that there are uncommited changes for the config file on the master branch (I'm not going to merge that master), so I have to stash first.